# Plot window disappears when minimised

Tags: r, linux, user-interface, ubuntu, plot

I've a new laptop so I reinstall R on it (3.2.3) on a linux mint 17.3.

When I plot, the plot window appears but does not appear in the bottom bar. If I minimize the plot window it disappears.. And when I try to plot an another plot it never appears.

I have to write `dev.off()` and then re-plot in order to show the new plot window. And I have to do that for every new plot, any ideas why?

> edit : When I do alt+tab I can see the plot icon and maximize it again.

[image]

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_BE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=fr_BE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_BE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_BE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_BE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_BE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_BE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Do you have multiple screens? Maybe use different GUI, RStudio?

Comment: No only one screen. I'll test RStudio but it would be nice to understand why this problem occurs.

Comment: Does this occur as well when you plot in new graphic device, i.e. `dev.new()`

Comment: Yes exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

1.Right Click On the bottom panel or the taskbar

[image: Right Click On the bottom panel or the taskbar]

2.Then scroll down to the end of the list and find the "Window List" option and then select it.

[image]

3.Then Click on the "Add" option.
[image]

Now you will have a tab on the taskbar and all the minimized windows will be shown there.

You can also try "Window Selector" option but I personally prefer Window List